# NVIDIA Cards compatible with Mac

Tags: mac, thunderbolt, gpu

I have a MacBook Air Intel so terrible graphics.
I want to get an eGPU. But all I can find for compatibility is AMD.
NVIDIA is so much more cheaper. (And I know theres a graphics card shortage for NVIDIA currently, but it is getting better).

so this brings me to the final question:

What Nvidia Graphics Cards are compatible with macOS big sur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple haven't been friends* with NVidia in quite a few years - here's the list of compatible Macs & GPUs - https://support.apple.com/HT208544 - all AMD.

For a time NVidia made their own drivers for add-in GPUs, mainly for the Mac Pros that had interchangeable cards like a regular PC. They stopped doing that at High Sierra so there is no NVidia support after that, other than for Mac models that shipped with NVidia when new [none of which will be able to run Mojave or newer I would guess, because of the lack of Metal2 support].

*Article from AppleInsider - [Apple's management doesn't want Nvidia support in macOS, and that's a bad sign for the Mac Pro](https://appleinsider.com/articles/19/01/18/apples-management-doesnt-want-nvidia-support-in-macos-and-thats-a-bad-sign-for-the-mac-pro)

Comment: nooooooooo.... well, thanks... i like NVIDIA because they are way more cheaper... guess its back to windows then...